# how to setup IPs from different subnet on 1 network card, Centos 6.6

Tags: linux, networking, ip

one centos 6.6 server, need add 15 Ips to it, my boss gives me 15 Ips from 2 different subnet.

```
server Ip 173.245.7xx.xxx

ips 173.245.7xx.xxx/29
    23.27.1xxx.xxx/28
```

this is what I did, all the ips in 173.245.7xx.xxx/29 works fine, all the ips in 23.27.1xxx.xxx/28 I can ping it from other server but can't ssh login. Data-Centre said they didn't block any port, I already turn off iptables.

```
**ifcfg-eth0**
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=68:05:ca:xx:xx:xx
IPV6INIT=no
MTU=1500
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID="700defb9-1b49-46d1-932c-xxxxxxxx"
IPADDR=173.245.7xx.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
DNS2=8.8.8.8
GATEWAY=173.245.7xx.xxx
DNS1=72.13.80.2
USERCTL=no

**ifcfg-eth0:1**
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=68:05:ca:xx:xx:xx
IPV6INIT=no
MTU=1500
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID="700defb9-1b49-46d1-932c-xxxxx"
IPADDR=173.245.7xx.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
DNS2=8.8.8.8
GATEWAY=173.245.7xx.xxx
DNS1=72.13.80.2
USERCTL=no

**ifcfg-eth0:4**
DEVICE=eth0:4
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=68:05:ca:xx:xx:xx
IPV6INIT=no
MTU=1500
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID="ae86ac55-3eeb-41d5-b708-xxxxxxxxx"
IPADDR=23.27.1xx.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
DNS2=8.8.8.8
GATEWAY=173.245.7xx.xxx
DNS1=72.13.80.2
USERCTL=no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ping the server from other computers the connections should be fine.  Please verify this...it will narrow the problem down.

- If you can ping all the addresses:

  - Your problem is with your ssh config
  - Look at your ssh.config file.  This should be at /etc/ssh or /etc/sshd/
- Verify the line in there labeled "listenAddress" is either 0.0.0.0 (not a best practice) or the address you are trying to connect on.  Take a look at this post it might have your [answer](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=27036).

Comment: thanks, you are right, the ldap server didn't add other group of IP to the ListenAddress. thank you for your help.

Comment: @user254049 If this answer helped you, please [click the check mark](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate that it solved your problem, and to award points to the user who wrote it.